# ERROR: file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\instant\storage\framework/sessions/FF): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, caching, xampp, shared-hosting

I am trying to upload my laravel project from Xampp to shared hosting, but I get the error:

> file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\resido\storage\framework/sessions/Jmmr9HI35UYdhIfZLDTVlLGjCy5AHiuVK9NfOQuT):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

when I delete the file app/bootstrap/cache/config.php, the application works. however, all the changes I made while working with xampp is gone and I get the old view from the application template.

I have tried:

- composer dump-autoload
- php artisan config:clear

Answer (score 9):

Go to boostrap folder and delete everything inside cache folder.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsRMR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by xampp, try to move your project folder to desktop & run this command: `php artisan serve` in your project's new location & it will work.
For more information read this official laravel documentation about [Serving Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#installation)

Comment: I have done this but when I tried to load the application with the address provided by artisan serve, I get the error:  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (SQL: select * from `menus` where `status` = published) (View: C:\Users\Shadowwalker\Desktop\mdl\platform\themes\resido\partials\header.blade.php) (View: C:\Users\Shadowwalker\Desktop\mdl\platform\themes\resido\partials\header.blade.php)

Comment: did you activated mysql server?

Comment: I just ran the PHP artisan serve as suggested

Comment: you have to activate MySQL from XAMPP also,

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the read and write permission to C:\xampp\htdocs\resido\storage\framework\sessions

Comment: how do I do this please?

Comment: Please I am new to Laravel and PHP. can you tell me how to go about this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).